# How to dynamically change ffmpeg output resolution when transcoding mkv file with variable frame size?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mkv

I have an MKV file where the first frame is 320x180 and from the second frame on everything is 1366x768. How to handle this with ffmpeg to automatically recognize the largest frame and set output resolution accordingly? I have many MKV files with different resolutions so setting it beforehand is not an option.

Comment: FFmpeg can't know maximum size unless it decodes and inspects the full stream. An inspection pass is needed.

Comment: I cannot find a way to do this with ffmpeg/ffprobe. Is there any option that could achieve this inspection?